# Getting data from forecast_io using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm pretty new to Ruby and would like to use it in a project in school. I've done the blog tutorial and I have a little understanding of how it works.

The question:
Can someone give me a tip on how to start to get data from the forecast_io API? A simple request to get some data to my page. Where should I start?

Thanks!

Comment: The [forecase_io](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby) gem is likely a good place to start. This question is a bit overly broad and, while SO is a great resource, you should not ask people to do your homework for you.

Comment: Well it's not really a homework but a framework I choose to work with in a project and I was looking for some startup tips. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [forecast_io](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby) gem helps you here. First you need an API key. You can get the API key through registering [here](https://developer.forecast.io/register). Then the [forecast_io github readme](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby) helps you.

```
Forecast::IO.api_key = 'this-is-your-api-key'
forecast = Forecast::IO.forecast(37.8267, -122.423) # params are: latitude, longitude
forecast.currently # gives you the current forecast datapoint
forecast.currently.summary # =>"Mostly Cloudy"
```

You can read the [forecast.io API docs](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is always [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/). If you search for forecast.io there, it will point you to a suitable [gem](https://github.com/darkskyapp/forecast-ruby).